# I want to show fix time and calculate remaining

Tags: vb.net, datetime, time, timestamp

i have a start time e.g. 12:00:00 and end time is 14:00:00
I want to calculate the difference which is 2 hours.
and show the user that 2 hours time with tickling.

how to do in vb.net?
should I use AJAX timer???

Comment: I recommend that you rephrase your question as it isn't entirely clear what the question is. Can you amend the question with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambigious. I will answer it as I understand. Firstly add 2 hours start time of exam as end time. Substract system time from end time. Update it with a timer .

Comment: Actually You told me exactly how to do it

thanks